# BHO how to replace javascript event handler result?

Tags: c#, javascript, event-handling, bho

Because drag a image which in hyperlink , can't get "FileDrop" or "DIB" data, so I want write a BHO using C# to enhance Drag Drop image.

I have injected dragstart event on document, it's worked fine, but:

If javascript have set ondragstart event handler like this:

```
<script>
ondragstart = function(){
  var obj = event.srcElement;
  if(obj.tagName == "A"){
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", "TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
  }
  window.document.title = event.srcElement.tagName;
}
document.attachEvent("ondragstart", ondragstart);
</script>
```

AND BHO ondragstart event handler :

```
...
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(src))
{
    try
    {
        var info = WinInetAPI.GetUrlCacheEntryInfo(src);
        src = info.lpszLocalFileName;
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    eventObj.dataTransfer.setData("Text", src);
}
...
```

The finally result is : TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT.

In debugger, I can see BHO ondragstart event handler invoked before javascript event handler.

So , is there anyway to invoke BHO event handler after javascript event handler?

I'm sorry for my English.
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:
In BHO Event handler , add the following code:

(eventObj as IHTMLEventObj).cancelBubble = true;

This problem ravel me the whole day

Comment: I am trying to do something similar to you - could you possibly send me some example code?  I'm new to BHOs and cannot figure out how to hook into the internet explorer drag and drop events.